# multiple select SQL statements in one table each statement a column

Tags: sql, database, select

I have this select queries

```
SELECT r.ID, p.Pregunta 
FROM RESPUESTAS r, PREGUNTAS p 
WHERE r.ID_Pregunta = p.ID 

SELECT r.ID, u.Nombre 
FROM RESPUESTAS r, USUARIOS u 
WHERE r.ID_Usuario = u.ID

SELECT r.ID, o.Region 
FROM RESPUESTAS r, REGIONES o 
WHERE r.ID_Region = o.ID

SELECT r.ID, s.Nombre 
FROM RESPUESTAS r, SUCURSALES s
WHERE r.ID_Sucursal = s.ID

SELECT r.ID, d.Nombre 
FROM RESPUESTAS r, DEPARTAMENTOS d
WHERE r.ID_Departamento = d.ID

SELECT r.ID, p.Nombre 
FROM RESPUESTAS r, PRODUCTOS p
WHERE r.ID_Producto = p.ID
```

i want to display each of them as a column with a single query (`r.ID` can should be the same column for all) i know i may use an `INNER JOIN` but i don't know have to do this

What will happen if any of them doesn't have any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.ID
    ,p.Pregunta 
    ,u.Nombre 
    ,o.Region 
    ,s.Nombre 
    ,d.Nombre 
    ,p.Nombre 
FROM RESPUESTAS r
LEFT JOIN PREGUNTAS p 
    ON r.ID_Pregunta = p.ID 
LEFT JOIN USUARIOS u 
    ON r.ID_Usuario = u.ID
LEFT JOIN REGIONES o 
    ON r.ID_Region = o.ID
LEFT JOIN SUCURSALES s
ON r.ID_Sucursal = s.ID
LEFT JOIN DEPARTAMENTOS d
ON r.ID_Departamento = d.ID
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOS p
ON r.ID_Producto = p.ID
```

The records that don't exist will come in as `null` as long as the ID exists in Table `RESPUESTAS`.

Comment: and is it possible to make them appear as null if it doesn't exist?

Comment: if the ID doesn't exist in RESPUESAS but it does in a sub table?  Change `Left Join` to `FULL OUTER JOIN` and leave all else the same.

Comment: although you will have to add ON clauses so the other tables line up properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.ID, p.Pregunta, u.Nombre,  o.Region, s.Nombre, d.Nombre, p.Nombre
FROM RESPUESTAS r inner join  PREGUNTAS p on r.ID_Pregunta = p.ID
  inner join USUARIOS u on r.ID_Usuario = u.ID
  inner join REGIONES o on r.ID_Region = o.ID
  inner join SUCURSALES s on r.ID_Sucursal = s.ID
  inner join DEPARTAMENTOS d on r.ID_Departamento = d.ID
  inner join PRODUCTOS p on r.ID_Producto = p.ID
```

Comment: it seems the OP does not want to lose records that are missing from one of the tables.